# mysqladmin - u root -p ping is not executing

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqladmin

I am getting the below error in mysql while trying to ping. i am using mysql version 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1. when ever i use mysqladmin i am getting the below error.

Please suggest how to clear this issue

```
karthick.g.s@sumtwo:~$ mysqladmin -u root -p ping
Warning: mysqladmin: unknown variable 'loose-local-infile=1'
mysqladmin: unknown variable 'local-infile=1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have:

```
local-infile=1
loose-local-infile=1
```

In your `[client]` section on `/etc/my.cnf` , `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/home/karthick.g.s/.my.cnf` or somewhere else.

Change it to a `[mysql]` section so it doesn't affect mysqladmin.

You can also do:

```
$ mysqladmin --no-defaults -u root -p ping
```

Comment: Again Thanks jynus issue has been fixed using above solution.